# Can Meteor preserve object references between server and client?

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to preserve pointers (object references) when you send data from the server to the client with Meteor? My initial tests say No, but perhaps there is another way to do this.

Here are server-side and client-side scripts:

Server.js

```
Meteor.methods({
  test: function test() {
  var object = {
      key: ['value']
    }
    var output = {
      object: object
    , reference: object.key
    }

    console.log(output.reference[0])
    output.object.key[0] = "changed"
    console.log(output.reference[0])

    return output
  }
})
```

Server output:

```
// value
// changed
```

Client.js

```
Meteor.call("test", testCallback)

function testCallback(error, data) {
  if (!error) {
    console.log(data.reference)
    data.object.key[0]= "edited"
    console.log(data.reference)
  }
}
```

Client output in the console:

```
// changed
// changed
```

Comment: if it was possible we probably would not need databases :) change your client side data on the client and it will be changed on the server side database as well

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, although subscriptions do something similar. If your data is not in a collection, you can still publish it (see `this.added` and friends in the Meteor docs), and the data will show up in a collection  in the client.